# How to update message in dialog from intent service?

Tags: android, android-dialog, intentservice

I want to update message inside a dialog through an intent service. I have called an intent service like this:

```
Boolean checkNetworkBeforeSync = NetworkHelper.hasNetworkAccess(this);

if (checkNetworkBeforeSync){
    MaterialDialog dialogSync = new MaterialDialog.Builder(EnterDataView.this)
        .title("Please Wait")
        .content("Uploading Data...")
        .progress(true, 0)
        .cancelable(false)
        .show();

    Intent serviceIntent = new Intent(this, UploadService.class);
    startService(serviceIntent);
}else{
    Toast.makeText(this, "Sync failed: You're not connected to the internet.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}
```

The intent service uploads the SQLite data to the server. I have the exact number of data that are to be uploaded in the intent service but I want to update the user about how much data has been uploaded. I am using broadcast receivers to close the dialog when the upload task finishes like this:

```
private BroadcastReceiver uBroadcastReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        String checkSyncStatus = intent.getStringExtra("CheckUploadStatus");
        if(checkSyncStatus.equals("true")){
            dialogSync.dismiss();

        }
    }
};
```

My question how can I update the message in the dialog to something like 'Uploaded data 100 out of 2000'?

Comment: make your `MaterialDialog dialogSync` global variable, and set it's text once you need to update it

Comment: @VladyslavMatviienko will I update the dialog message in intent service?

Comment: you can at least try. If it says something about UI thread - just put your UI code inside a handler

Comment: are you intending the received broadcasts from outside of your application or just locally within your application?

Comment: @RichardStokes I'm receiving it locally within my application.

Comment: Considering that you are intending to use the broadcasts for local use only I would suggest you change to a LocalBroadcast so that it doesn't open your application to external processes.